# How to add shortcode in wppb plugin boilerplate

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I want to add shortcode in wppb plugin boilerplate 
here is a link for boilerplate generator *http://wppb.me*
please tell how it will works?
your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference to add shortcode in functions.php or a plugin.

Please refer to the [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to get some idea about how to add your shortcode.

Also, there is a github [issue](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/issues/262) about this.

Comment: In the boilerplate plugin mentioned in the original question it's a little different because you have to load your functions like in the answer above.

Comment: In the boilerplate plugin mentioned in the original question it's a little different because you have to load your functions like in the answer above.

Answer (score 30):

Came across this whiling looking for the solution to the exact same problem, found the solution  on the github for the wordpress boilerplate plugin: https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/issues/262

```
private function define_public_hooks() {
    $this->loader->add_action( 'init', $plugin_public, 'register_shortcodes' );
}
```

In your define_hooks function in your class-pluginName.php file (with the rest of your add actions add into the above action.

Then in your class-pluginName-public.php file create the register_shortcodes function to the shortcodes.

```
public function register_shortcodes() {
  add_shortcode( 'shortcode', array( $this, 'shortcode_function') );
  add_shortcode( 'anothershortcode', array( $this, 'another_shortcode_function') );
}
```

And then create your shortcode functions.

Comment: This helped me a great deal.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add_shortcode( 'course_link', array( $plugin_public,'wdm_learndash_course_link_shortcode') );

You can use this in includes-> class-{plugin-name}.php->private define public hooks() inside plugin boilerplate

Use [course_link] wherever you want on the frontend.
Use $plugin_admin for admin side.